# Spartan 6 Internal Memory

Tags: fpga, xilinx, memory, programmable-logic, spartan-6

I am referring to below datasheet of IC [XC6SLX45-L1FGG484C-ND](http://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=XC6SLX45-L1FGG484C-ND). As per Digikey portal, it has Total RAM Bits = 2138112

[image: Digikey link]

**If I want use internal RAM memory is there any specific pins associated with xilinx FPGA? Or I can use any GPIO pins and configure it in software?**

Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to configure the FPGA, then the memory is available wherever you want. But I think if you're not familiar with this you shouldn't start with a $72 part.

Comment: Looking at this part the OP must be dreaming about producing a product. Looks like the only way to purchase these is in increments of 60 parts. So be prepared to fork over some serious cash.

Comment: It is used in product and there are many peripherals other than memory such as solenoid valves, motor driver, adc, OPTO's, Printer,PC 104 (CPU) board etc...

Answer (score 2):

The memory is internal to the FPGA, you access it from logic programmed into the FPGA.

So if you wanted to use an FPGA purely as a RAM chip  then you would need to write the logic to interface the internal ram to the outside world.

The pinout could be just about anything you wanted but using the global input buffers for clock/enable type signals would give a slight performance benefit.

Having said that why would anyone pay $72 for a 261 kByte slow and power hungry memory chip?

Comment: It is used in product and there are many peripherals other than memory such as solenoid valves, motor driver, adc, OPTO's, Printer,PC 104 (CPU) board etc... Is it good to use internal memory or to use ext memory for fast processing?

Comment: For memory accessed by logic within the FPGA use the internal memory. For memory accessed by other devices outside the FPGA use a dedicated memory chip.

Comment: i have 12 bit adc ( used in 3 nos), do u mean external memory should be used?

Comment: Do whatever works best for the design in question. I don't know your design, I don't have your schematic, I don't know how the software is structured. How do you expect anyone here to be able to answer that question?